# BLAZOR + MVC - passing data from Blazor page to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have MVC project, which uses some Blazor pages. What I need now is to pass data back from Blazor page to MVC controller. Is that even possible? My solution is to write data to the DB and get them after in MVC...but I don't like this way. Someone knows a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have a method in Blazor that calls (POST, GET) your MVC controller, is that what you want?

Comment: To be more speciffic, I need to pass list of products...let's say  List<Product> out of Blazor page to the Controller action. I'm not sure, that's possible in this way.

Comment: Why? You can do whatever the MVC action is doing from within the Blazor component. That's sort of the whole point: writing client-side functionality in C# so you can utilize all the same code, tools, and libraries that you could server-side.

Comment: I don't agree @ChrisPratt, what about PDF? I'm using Rotativa to create PDF reports in MVC. Haven't found a way, how to use it in Blazor component. I have made an interactive page in Blazor and I need to show results in PDF as well. I don't want another PDF generator for Blazor component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this, you need to use an HTTP client, such as `HttpClient`. See an example on the Microsoft documentation site here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1.