# HttpClient requests not recognizing session ASP.NET Core 6 MVC from razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

Not sure where else to look, what I am trying to accomplish is the following

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with a controller like this:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveNameToDataBase(NameModel nameModel)
    {
        if (CheckSessionIfUserIsLoggedIn())
        {
            PostComment(nameModel)
            return JsonStringThatShowsSuccess
        }
        else 
        { 
            return JsonStringThatShowsAnError 
        }
    }
}
```

If I call the method from the browser it works correctly, however, I am using a Blazor component in order to prevent the whole page from reloading to post

```
@code {    
[Parameter]
public string NewNameToPut { get; set; } = string.Empty;

[Parameter]
public string NewNameExtraParam { get; set; } = string.Empty;

// On click event
private async Task CreateRootComment()
{
    NameModel nameModel = new NameModel(NewNameToPut);

    // update namemmodel
    ...

    // Set up request
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}MyController/SaveNameToDataBase");

    @* Add body to request *@
    request.Content = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nameModel)
    );

    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng");
    //  requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zu;q=0.6");

    HttpClient client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}
}
```

The request is sent and triggered successfully however the session variables are not recognized. The session contains a key-value that is set to true when the user logs in and for some reason it is not found when the HttpClient does the request, but it is found when the browser makes it via mouseclick, form submission, or JS runtime.

Perhaps there is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server) that I missed from here? Any articles or guides are also helpful

Comment: I supposed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117930/blazor-mvc-passing-data-from-blazor-page-to-mvc-controller) answers my question, so no solution i guess :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually switched from MVC to MVVM and just injected the required services so that the blazor component can be independent from the controller through the use of
the [HttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0)